# Rails 4.0.5 and feedBacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am running Rails 4.0.5 and am trying to install [wwidea/feedbacker](https://github.com/wwidea/feedbacker) into my app.

One of the few instructions is to add the following line to config/application.rb

```
config.paths['db/migrate'] += Feedbacker::Engine.paths['db/migrate'].existent
```

But when I do I get the follow error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<Rails::Paths::Path:0x007f5f120db830>
/var/www/development/config/application.rb:32:in `<class:Application>'
/var/www/development/config/application.rb:15:in `<module:Laflife>'
/var/www/development/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/development/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't see the bug

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you didn't install the Gem yet. Make sure to run bundle install before everything else. (Note that in your Gemfile you should have gem 'feedbacker', '~> 0.2.1')